# In what direction would current flow in the coil?

Tags: electromagnetism, magnetic-fields, electric-fields, home-experiment

I have two circular coils facing each other in parallel. Through one coil current flows. I move the second coil in a parallel fashion.

What is the direction of current induced on the moving coil?

*Acc. to me, there should be no induced current as in parallel movement, the flux doesn't change.*

Comment: Does "parallel" mean along the axis or along the plane of the coils?

Comment: Probably same Axis

Comment: If you move the coil by a long distance, the flux will approach zero. So there is a flux change, and hence induced current. Lenz's law provides the direction.

Answer (score 0):

The magnetic field on and near the axis decreases as you move away from a coil.              As the second coil moves away from the first coil the flux through it would decrease.    By Lenz's, law, this would produce a current in the second coil in the same direction as the current in the first coil.